# Monotonic Transformation

Tags: production-function, producer-theory, profit-maximization

How does positive monotonic transformation of production function effect the resulting profit function? 
For example if we had production function $f(x) $ and that gave profit function $\pi(p,w)$. Now if we transform the production function as let's say $f(x)^{\mu}$ where $\mu>0$, how would that effect the profit function?

Comment: Is $\mu > 1$ or not?

Comment: It is >0. But if >1 is simpler, assume that.

Comment: I think if you finish your answer (see my comment http://economics.stackexchange.com/a/8867/1601 ) to your other question , you will also find this answer.